# Postgres query taking too long

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I've looked at many of the primary mistakes people make when executing queries and I'm not sure why it takes so long to execute.

I removed all of the fields I am not using, this query fetches about 10,000 records.

What can I do to optimize my query.

```
SELECT ord.id              AS ord_id, 
       oli.id              AS oli_id, 
       ord.dealer_code__c  AS ord_dealer_code__c, 
       ord.recordtypeid    AS ord_recordtypeid, 
       ord.order_number__c AS ord_order_number__c, 
       ord.status          AS ord_status, 
       ord.opportunityid   AS ord_opportunityid, 
       ord.sfid            AS ord_sfid, 
       ord.pricebook2id    AS ord_pricebook2id, 
       cont.opportunity__c AS cont_opportunity__c, 
       cont.sfid           AS cont_sfid, 
       opp.sfid            AS opp_sfid, 
       opp.recordtypeid    AS opp_recordtypeid, 
       opp.pricebook2id    AS opp_pricebook2id, 
       accban.sfid         AS accban_sfid, 
       accban.ban__c       AS accban_ban__c, 
       usr.sfid            AS usr_sfid 
FROM   fullsbxsalesforce.order ord 
       LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.contract cont 
              ON ord.contractid = cont.sfid 
       LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.opportunity opp 
              ON cont.opportunity__c = opp.sfid 
       LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.user usr 
              ON ( ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_bd__c 
                    OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_co_sell__c 
                    OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.rep_dealer_code__c 
                    OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_secondary__c ) 
       LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.account_ban_tax_id__c accban 
              ON ord.ban_number__c = accban.ban__c 
       LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.orderitem oli 
              ON oli.sfid = (SELECT sfid 
                             FROM   fullsbxsalesforce.orderitem oli 
                             WHERE  ord.sfid = oli.orderid 
                             LIMIT  1) 
WHERE  ord.recordtypeid = 'specificid' 
       AND ( ord.status IN ( 'Submitted', 'Pending EIP eSignature', 
                             'Partially Shipped', 
                                                 'In-Fulfilment Queue', 
                             'Locked', 'Pending Approval', 'Resubmitted', 
                             'Pending Order', 
                             'Pending Customer Completion', 'Backorder', 'Draft' 
                             , 
                                   'Credit Card Declined', 
                             'External System', 'Shipped/Pending Activation', 
                                   'Shipped/Partially Activated' 
                                                 , 'SAP Order Does not exist', 
                             'Approved', 'Submit Failed for an Easy Order', 
                                   'Pending e-Signature', 
                                                 'e-Signature Complete', 
                             'Credit Card Decline (Hold)', 'Pre-Order', 
                             'In Shipping Queue' 
                               ) 
              OR ( ord.status = 'Shipped' 
                   AND ord.hasmsisdn__c = false 
                   AND ord.last_status_change__c >= CURRENT_DATE - 
                                                    INTERVAL '7' day ) );
```

Thanks
-Tim

EDIT:
thankyou for all of your help so far, the query has finished at 25 minutes returning 9.5k records.

I have changed it from java to postgres and added sql to the tags.

Thanks everyone so far

EDIT 2: I have performed an "EXPLAIN" on my query

```
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4283.25..5032.80 rows=2 width=256)
   Join Filter: (((ord.dealer_code__c)::text = (usr.dealer_code_bd__c)::text) OR ((ord.dealer_code__c)::text = (usr.dealer_code_co_sell__c)::text) OR ((ord.dealer_code__c)::text = (usr.rep_dealer_code__c)::text) OR ((ord.dealer_code__c)::text = (usr.dealer_code_secondary__c)::text))
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4283.25..4298.93 rows=1 width=237)
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.34..12.01 rows=1 width=233)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.25..7.92 rows=1 width=215)
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.17..6.99 rows=1 width=158)
                           ->  Index Scan using hc_idx_order_recordtypeid on "order" ord  (cost=0.08..2.90 rows=1 width=139)
                                 Index Cond: ((recordtypeid)::text = 'specificid'::text)
                                 Filter: (((status)::text = ANY ('{Submitted,"Pending EIP eSignature","Partially Shipped","In-Fulfilment Queue",Locked,"Pending Approval",Resubmitted,"Pending Order","Pending Customer Completion",Backorder,Draft,"Credit Card Declined","External System","Shipped/Pending Activation","Shipped/Partially Activated","SAP Order Does not exist",Approved,"Submit Failed for an Easy Order","Pending e-Signature","e-Signature Complete","Credit Card Decline (Hold)",Pre-Order,"In Shipping Queue"}'::text[])) OR (((status)::text = 'Shipped'::text) AND (NOT hasmsisdn__c) AND (last_status_change__c >= (('now'::cstring)::date - '7 days'::interval day))))
                           ->  Index Scan using hcu_idx_contract_sfid on contract cont  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=38)
                                 Index Cond: ((ord.contractid)::text = (sfid)::text)
                     ->  Index Scan using hcu_idx_opportunity_sfid on opportunity opp  (cost=0.08..0.93 rows=1 width=57)
                           Index Cond: ((cont.opportunity__c)::text = (sfid)::text)
               ->  Index Scan using hcu_idx_account_ban_tax_id__c_ban__c on account_ban_tax_id__c accban  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=28)
                     Index Cond: ((ord.ban_number__c)::text = (ban__c)::text)
         ->  Index Scan using hcu_idx_orderitem_sfid on orderitem oli  (cost=4282.91..4286.92 rows=1 width=23)
               Index Cond: ((sfid)::text = ((SubPlan 1))::text)
               SubPlan 1
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..4282.83 rows=1 width=19)
                       ->  Seq Scan on orderitem oli_1  (cost=0.00..25696.96 rows=6 width=19)
                             Filter: ((ord.sfid)::text = (orderid)::text)
   ->  Seq Scan on "user" usr  (cost=0.00..555.20 rows=35733 width=74)
(22 rows)
```

Comment: How long is too long? Have you tried `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the items table, and why just the first item in the order?

Comment: Have you tried EXPLAIN? and do you really want to retrieve 10000 rows?

Comment: ctznkane525, I just need to know whether or not any order item exists because if 1 exists there is no need to validate the rest, if none exist then I will create them all
@scarywombat  -- yes i really need all 10,000 rows, I have not tried explain
shmosel, its over 20 minutes now and I have not tried explain

Comment: Do you have any indices on the columns involved in the joins or in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: id suspect this is a problem - this join fullsbxsalesforce.user and for this...fullsbxsalesforce.orderitem...just do an exists if you don't need the data....you are joining on a subquery...unnecessarily expensive id think

Comment: There is an awful lot of SQL, and a total lack of Java, in that "Java query".

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `java` and not with `sql`? Does this query run slower in Java than if you run it directly on the CLI client? If not, you shouldn't tag with "java".

Comment: @tim bidgeleisen , correct me if I’m wrong but I think you are asking if I can cut out any of the columns using context clues from other columns? If that is your question then I don’t think so

Comment: Optimizing SQL query performance is a question that belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com/, where you can ask questions about [topics](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) like ... ***Advanced Querying*** including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and **query-performance**.

Comment: No, I'm asking whether you have any indices on the join or where columns.  If the answer is no, then you have some room for improvement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have a few indices already set up. all the ids are indexed as well as ord.status and ord.recordtypeid

Comment: Please review the execution plan. Based on the timings you described, it sounds like you have a pretty significant loop and/or blocking taking place somewhere.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the 4 different dealer code columns in the `user` table (`dealer_code_bd__c`, `dealer_code_co_sell__c`, `rep_dealer_code__c`, and `dealer_code_secondary__c`)?

Comment: @andreas I only had one on rep_dealer_code__c , but now I have indexed the other 3 you have listed as well

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query to the question.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). This has also been asked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198318/19-minute-query-returning-9-5k-rows-how-to-optimize (I suggest to delete the question here as it is a better fit for dba)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has also been asked on dba.stackexchange.com where it's a better fit